# Как отключить лампочки и отвертки в Visual Studio от 2015 до 2022

Tags: visual-studio

Очень мешают и раздражают. Как их отключить навсегда. Никогда за 20 лет работы не пользовался!

[image: DebilsHelp]

В настройках нет необходимого пункта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пользуюсь C#

Comment: *"Никогда за 20 лет работы не пользовался"* - странно, что за 20 лет работы вы не освоили ориентацию в настройках VS

Answer (score 0):

Лампочки выключаются посредством Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> View -> Enable IntelliSense Error Fix Suggestion.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подобные настройки отсутствуют